# Does the Divergence theorem hold on finite perimeter sets with measure zero?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

From the general divergence theorem, we know that 
$$\int_A div(u) d\mathcal{L}^n= \int_{\partial^* A}  u\cdot \nu d\mathcal{H}^{n-1} $$
where $\nu(x)$ is the normal unit vector at $x\in \partial^* A$ and  $\partial^* A$ is the [reduced boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caccioppoli_set#The_reduced_boundary) of $A$.

Now if I take $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ to be a $\mathcal{L}^n$ null set with finite perimeter, the left hand side would be zero, but how can I conclude the right hand side is also zero?

Comment: To my understanding you need $A$ to have at least something like Lipschitz boundary in order to use the divergence theorem.

Comment: @Ian Thank you. Now I have to figure out another way to write the distributional derivative of $\chi_A$ for $A$ that does not have Lipschitz boundary  :)

Comment: (Edited the question to finite perimeter sets.)

Comment: If $A$ is a null set, isn't its measure theoretic boundary empty? If your definition is compatible with the one [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390097/about-measure-theoretic-interior-and-boundary), it is.

Comment: @Daniel Thank you! I think what I meant was the reduced boundary, the definition is here en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caccioppoli_set#The_reduced_boundary I will think more about it, the reduced boundary should be a null set.